# Change the SuiteBar Color

Tags: css, branding, online

I need to change the blue top **ribbon** color for an **Office 365 Team Site**. I have read dozens of instructions including those in these forums, but they don't seem to work. Some of the instructions are dated because MS is always changing things. Specifically, I have tried editing the CSS and changing **suitebar** colors. I have tried adding **recommended entries** to the CSS file. The closest I have come is to edit the `palette001.spcolor` file. This changes the colors correctly when viewing the available themes, but does not take when the theme is applied. I feel like I'm losing my mind - this shouldn't be so difficult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using CSS, customize it from the admin section. Here is an excellent step by step instruction from Microsoft:
[Customize the Office 365 theme for your organization](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Office-365-theme-for-your-organization-8275da91-7a48-4591-94ab-3123a3f79530?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

In case CSS is your only option, use the following style:

```
div.o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo .o365cs-topnavBGColor-2, div.o365cs-base.o365cst.o365spo.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2, div.o365cs-base .o365cs-topnavLinkBackground-2 {
    background-color: Red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the link you provided earlier. Their instructions say to click on "Settings -> Organization Profile". I don't have an Organization Profile listed under settings or in Site Settings. I also looked in the SharePoint Admin Center as well. My CSS file doesn't have the entry you listed. I tried adding it, but it didn't change anything. Thanks.

Comment: Put a # symbol in front of your CSS code and it worked. THANKS!!!